# Pass one parameter in multiple arguments function in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My angular function is defined in a service somethin like,

```
$delegate.isConfigurable = function (product, config) {
                if (product) {
                    ///.....
                }
                return config.getDetail();
            };
```

Now, on the `controller`, I am calling this through:

`mySer.isConfigurable(null, conf);`

But passing `null` looks a little awakard to me.

I tried calling `mySer.isConfigurable(conf);` but this makes `conf` match to `first parameter` of the function.

Instead, are there any other way of passing only `conf` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can just switch the order that the parameters are defined?

```
$delegate.isConfigurable = function (config, product) {
            if (product) {
                ///.....
            }
            return config.getDetail();
        };
```

Then you can call just `mySer.isConfigurable(conf);` and `product` be undefined in that case, and will evaluate to false.

Comment: Switching paramaters is fine.. but any generic ways of doing this ?

Comment: I don't believe there is. It may also be confusing to see the same function called with the only param actually being a different variable when it's called in different places. I suppose you could also make 2 separate helper functions that call this `isConfigurable` function with different parameters.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `null` then you need to interchange your function parameter like bellow.

```
$delegate.isConfigurable = function (config, product) {
                if (product) {
                    ///.....
                }
                return config.getDetail();
            };
```

And now if you call that function passing one parameter that will be the value of  `config` and `product` parameter will be passed as `undefined`.

```
 mySer.isConfigurable(conf);
```

Comment: Switching paramaters is fine.. but any generic ways of doing this ?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. Yes, this is how it is usually done. Mandatory params go first, exactly to avoid the issue you're having. Otherwise there should be tedious parsing of `arguments`, as the other answer explains.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a function that have varying number of parameters then you can use the `arguments object`

[Here is the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

> The arguments object is an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function.The arguments object is a local variable available within all functions

So your code will be

```
$delegate.isConfigurable = function() {
  var param = null,
    config = null;
  if (arguments && arguments.length == 2) {
    // you have param and config
    param = arguments[0];
    config = arguments[1];
  } else if (arguments && arguments.length == 1) {
    config = arguments[0];
  }
  return config.getDetail();
};
```

And you can call this by one or two or n number of param

```
mySer.isConfigurable(conf)
mySer.isConfigurable(param,conf)
mySer.isConfigurable(param1,param2,conf)
```